# Unexpected Result Tree Traversal - Python

Tags: python, tree, tree-traversal

I have an unexpected result where values of `self.path` and `self.path_temp` are different and the only way they are different is that one is updated by a string and another by a list all passed through function `trav` as arguments. Are lists somehow persistent in memory in python? A correct or detailed explanation would be appreciated!

PS: The correct one is `self.path` which is updated with the string.

```py
    def binaryTreePaths(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[str]:
                
        self.path = []
        temp = []
        self.path_temp = []

        
        def trav(root,path,temp):
            
            if root:
                
                path += str(root.val)
                temp.append(root.val)

                if root.right == None and root.left==None:
                    self.path.append('->'.join(path))
                    self.path_temp.append('->'.join(temp))
                
                    
                trav(root.left,path,temp)
                trav(root.right,path,temp)
        
        
        trav(root,'',temp)    
        print(self.path)
        print(self.path_temp)
```

Comment: What is `ls`???

Comment: My bad, it was supposed to be temp. But it was a typo when i was changing variable names. It doesnt change the issue functional wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `path` is a primitive value (a string) and `temp` is not. When you do

```
path += str(root.val)
```

You are actually creating a new string. Strings are immutable in Python. And so also, the caller of the function will not see any change in the `path` variable that it passed as argument.

It is a different story with `temp`. When you do

```
temp.append(root.val)
```

... you are mutating the `temp` list. This is the list that the caller passed as argument, and so the caller's list is mutated by this action. In all the recursive process there are several `temp` variable instances, but they all reference one and the same list. Every `append` affects all `temp` variable instances.

If you want `temp` to behave like `path`, then you must create a *new* list instead of mutating the existing one:

```
temp = temp + [root.val]
```

NB: don't shorten this to `temp += [root.val]`, as then again you are muting the original list.